# Azure load balancing with three websites

Tags: azure, load-balancing, round-robin

If I have three websites like web1.azurewebsites.net, web2...,web3... in the same region and want to have a loadbalancer that divides the traffic evenly amongst those websites (a so called round robin configuration). How can I accomplish this in azure?
I know that I can use the traffic manager but only if the websites are on different regions.

Sorry but very new to azure...

/Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you *need* to have three different web sites? Or can you have a single web site scaled up to multiple instances? (guide [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-scale/))

If you scale up, then it should use a built-in load balancer that is based on a hash of the user's IP + port, as described [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/08/microsoft-azure-load-balancing-services/).

And yes, traffic manager isn't really intended for *true* load balancing; it's a DNS-level redirection, mainly for improving performance based on geography.

Comment: Ok so scaling it is the way to do it then? Let's say that I want one backend website and three frontend websites. Then should I have one backend and one frontend(which I scale to three websites)? And when I scale they are automatically "load balanced" right?

Comment: Yes, if the sites have different content or purpose, then create them as different websites. You can independently scale the more popular website to use additional servers; the same code will be auto-deployed as Azure spins up the servers. And yes, the load balancing is automatically enabled with scaling. (Note that you also have the option of auto-scaling based on schedule or CPU usage)